# Parse.com Android API slow server call issue

Tags: android, database-design, parse-platform, batch-processing

So we are creating an Android and iOS app using parse.com backend.

The iOS app is great and can login and load data in a few seconds.  We define all queries in one big batch request and then call all of them to be done on Parse.com and then ALL results are sent back to us where we store them in a local database and while the screen is shown we show placeholders as we load images one by one… all good.

The issue is that on the Android API I don't have batch requests which means that I can't create just one query so I have to make multiple calls and that slows everything down…. for example to login and load the data takes around 60 seconds… obviously this isn’t acceptable

So my question is how do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make batch requests in Android you could always use the REST api as described here https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#objects-batch

There is nothing *so far* in the SDK from Parse to batch requests for Android.

You could also look at [Volley](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728), a networking library from Google that can take a lot of pain out of networking, with a simple and extendable API.

Comment: paste your query here.